# remove outliers by group in sql

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, data-science, sqldf

In my column in SQL Server, I must delete outliers for each group separately. Here are my columns

```
select
    customer, 
    sku,
    stuff, 
    action,
    acnumber,
    year
from
    mytable
```

Sample data:

```
     customer sku year stuff action
-----------------------------------
1         1    2 2017    10      0
2         1    2 2017    20      1
3         1    3 2017    30      0
4         1    3 2017    40      1
5         2    4 2017    50      0
6         2    4 2017    60      1
7         2    5 2017    70      0
8         2    5 2017    80      1
9         1    2 2018    10      0
10        1    2 2018    20      1
11        1    3 2018    30      0
12        1    3 2018    40      1
13        2    4 2018    50      0
14        2    4 2018    60      1
15        2    5 2018    70      0
16        2    5 2018    80      1
```

I must delete outlier from stuff variable, but separately by group `customer+sku+year`.

All that is below the 25th percentile and above 75 percentile should be considered an outlier and this principle must be respected for each group.

How to clear dataset for next working ?

Note, in this dataset, there is variable action (it tales value 0 and 1). It is not group variable, but outliers must be delete only for `ZERO(0)` categories of action variable.

in R language this is decided as

```
remove_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y <- x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA
  y
}

new <- remove_outliers(vpg$stuff)
vpg=cbind(new,vpg)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked at the Percentile Rank function? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percent-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: What you really should be posting is the table definition, sample data and desired output. And percentile of what? Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @user1443098 can you show it use on my data?

Comment: @ecp i try do it like in R language, function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y <- x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA
  y
} it is not work

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe:

```
DELETE mytable
WHERE PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY customer, sku, year ORDER BY stuff ) < .25 OR 
      PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY customer, sku, year  ORDER BY stuff ) > .75
```